# Dark statusbar/quicksettings theme on Oreo?

Tags: google-pixel, 8.0-oreo

I've updated my Google Pixel to Oreo. Now the statusbar and quick settings area have a light theme. Is it possible to change that back to the dark theme, like on previous versions of Android? The white background is way too bright... I didn't find any option in the settings.

[image: quicksettings]

Comment: Isn't there a system UI tuner, that can be activated by long press of settings?

Comment: @beeshyams I managed to activate the system UI tuner, but I can't find the option there either. It just allows me to hide statusbar icons.

Comment: I don't have the OS - it was a suggestion

Comment: I've got a Nexus 5x and it's the same issue - the theme has gone white with 8.0.0. I am attempting to find how to enable the substratum support, hopefully without rooting, as I've heard there are some ADB workarounds.

Comment: There's a "color inversion" option under Settings > Accessibility. Will that do?

Comment: Inverts color for entire device, not just menu - so no.

Comment: The only way I've been able to find is [substratum/andromeda](https://www.xda-developers.com/custom-themes-android-oreo-substratum/) hack. And it **is** a hack. `Andromeda (desktop) --(USB)--> Android (developer access) --> Substratum` to give the app access to android core UI commands. With how hard they're promoting it however, I doubt many haven't heard of it.

Answer (score 3):

Sony helped Google in implementing native support of RRO layers in Android O. This was previously used in many Xperia phones for a better system-wide theme support. In android custom rom and root community, [Project Substratum](https://substratum.review) is used for same. It also uses RRO layers thus provides better and more consistent theme than previous option CynogenMod Theme Engine (CMTE).

Till Oreo RRO layer patches and root were necessary for Substratum to work but as Oreo has native RRO layer support so it can be achieved in stock rom.For detailed method see [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/custom-themes-android-oreo-substratum/) and [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-dark-theme-android-oreo-without-root/) xda article.
@Tony Chiboucas has also mentioned the method in his comment.

P.S. For unrooted devices, this is a paid process.

Comment: Will this work on Nokia 8? It claims to be very close to pure Android 8.0.

Comment: @NVZ it should work either try yourself or search xda forum of your device.

Answer (score 0):

Android Oreo 8.1 introduced an automatic theme switch. It adjusts the theme depending on your wallpaper. If you have a sufficiently dark wallpaper the quicksettings area will use a dark theme, otherwise it uses a light theme.