# Settings dark background in Android 8

Tags: settings, quick-settings, 8.0-oreo

The upgrade to Android 8 changed the background of the settings and the roll down menus to white. This makes it harder for me to read (partially colourblind); how can I change the background again to black?

Comment: Duplicate Question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182313/dark-statusbar-quicksettings-theme-on-oreo

Answer (score 3):

Google has added a dark theme to many of dev previews of Android, but they always remove it at the last minute :(

So, unless the OEM skin on your device provides this option, it looks like your only course of action would be to [follow XDA's guide on installing a dark theme without root.](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-dark-theme-android-oreo-without-root/)

Comment: I would be prefer to have a solution that does not involve buying commercial software. Thanks for the information in any case.